# SQL Server Validation Failed Send Email

Tags: sql, sql-server, validation, email

I have a client looking to utilize SQL to email users when they have failed log in credentials 3 times. From what the client has told me, SQL should grab whatever user was attempting and email them that their account has entered credential wrong too many times. Client wants to use `sp_send_dbmail` The current expected results are as follows

- User enters password incorrectly 3 times
- SQL send email stating "User failed login too many times please reset password"

Is this achievable or is there something else that handles this type of query?

Comment: What is the login credential in question here?  Are you talking about an application level login, or a SQL Server login?  If this is an application password, don't use SQL Server for this.  Do the email in the app.

Comment: It is a web application. Unfortunately not much information was given to me how the web application works. My thought was write syntax in the app itself (Pretty sure it's using C#) and write out a validation function.

Comment: SQL Server is not a mass-mailer, it's a database. Use a mail client/library, perhaps from your webserver, to do this. `sp_send_dbmail` is designed for one off alerts to DBA or developer to alert critical errors, not as a mass mail solution. It could be done, but it's the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: I assumed so but wanted confirmation as I am still fairly new. My gut was telling me that SQL is not meant to be used in this manner. However the client is still persisting that we do it this way.